# Recovering Windows and/or system restore after faulty driver install

Tags: windows, crash, registry, drivers, system-restore

I installed HP sound driver yesterday and it BSOD-ed my windows and crashed it. System repair didn't help. system restore is corrupted, and startup recovery just says ""patch is preventing windows from starting". when I try to boot, it loads up to certain amount of time and then in just BSOD-s to 0x0000007b.

I disabled the new driver in registry, but it didn't help.
I then installed another windows copy on a new partition, and tried copying over the registry and system32\drivers folder, still the same issue.

Any further ideas? if I could somehow just use the files from system restore that are not corrupted, and leave the rest out, that would help but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstallation was the only way to go unfortunately. I tried replacing windows files, reintegrating registry.. nothing gave stable results. This is not a solution, as I was trying to fix the computer, not reinstall OS.